# Why is voltage across sampling capacitor going below 0V

Tags: sample-and-hold, 741-opamp

I am trying to design a sample and hold circuit for a project, but I am not understanding some of the results for my current simulation. When my control signal (V1) is turned off, the voltage over the capacitor goes below zero as it discharges. Why is this happening, how can I stop it?

I thought that I was creating some weird ground loop, but I have been doing a lot of reading and I  am confident that I have everything correctly configured.

[image]

Comment: That MOSfet is very big, with large capacitances on the same order of magnitude as the storage capacitor. Try a much smaller MOSfet. Even so, it will likely be a glitchy sampler, but less glitchy than it is currently.

Comment: A common solution is to use an analog switch such as the 4016,4066,4051,4052 and 4053. For higher performance there are some ADGxxx parts. The learned colleagues have already done an excellent job of explaining why your current circuit has issues.

Comment: The body diode doesn't help either! Either choose the right FET or use a pair, one reversed. You do also have to cope with the charge dumped via the gate capacitance too, so the right FET will minimise this capacitance.

Comment: "I am trying to design a sample and hold circuit for a project."  >>> Why don't  test dedicated IC as LF398 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your MOSFET is configured as a "[source follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain)", or "common drain". It does not have the behaviour of an "analogue switch" that you require in this application.

A source follower does as the name suggests; the MOSFET's source potential follows the gate as it rises and falls, but offset by an amount equal to the gate threshold voltage. That is, \$V_S = V_G - V_{GS(TH)}\$. However, the source potential cannot swing outside the limits imposed by whatever is available at its drain or source, and will be "clipped" to those extremes.

Here's an example of a source follower, and a graph of input and output signals, to illustrate this behaviour:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLdJmD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

The voltage \$V_{OUT}\$ at the MOSFET's source follows the gate voltage \$V_{IN}\$, node IN, except where it cannot. \$V_{OUT}\$ cannot exceed the 5V present at the drain, or fall below 0V imposed at the bottom of R1.

Also notice that when clipping is *not* occuring, \$V_{IN} - V_{OUT} = V_{GS(TH)} = 2V\$, the gate threshold voltage for this MOSFET. There is no "switching" action happening here.

Compare this to the following circuit, a "[common source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_source)" configuration where output is taken from the drain, which is expected to vary:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbquS4.png)</sup>

[image]

Clearly this is the switching behaviour you require. When the input "trigger" signal is high, the MOSFET acts like a very low resistance between drain and source (effectively connecting the drain OUT to 0V ground), and when the input is low that drain-source resistance is very high (disconnecting the drain from 0V).

Your error has been to assume that the MOSFET acts like a switch in both cases, where actually its behaviour depends very much on how you connect the drain and source. In your circuit, what you are seeing is the source following the digital gate voltage, but a couple of volts lower, and clipped by whatever potential is at the drain at the time.

These are the two things that need to happen for your MOSFET to act like an analogue switch:

- It must be configured as "common source", where you take output from the drain.
- The switching signal at the gate must always be *significantly* different from the whatever voltage you expect to appear at the source.

This latter point is because it is the potential difference between the gate and source (\$V_{GS}\$) that determines whether a MOSFET is "on" or "off", and drain potential has nothing to do with it. For an N-channel MOSFET, if the MOSFET has a gate threshold voltage of \$V_{GS}=2V\$, then to guarantee that it is "on", the signal applied to the gate must be at least 2V greater than the largest potential you ever expect to see at the source.

Conversely, to guarantee it is "off", you must provide a switching signal that is guaranteed to be less than the lowest potential you ever expect to be present at the source.

For a P-channel device, the conditions are reversed; to switch it on you must provide a gate potential that is at least \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ *lower* than the source.

The former point (use common source) means that the signal you wish to sample must be connected to the source, and the capacitor to be charged is the "load" at the drain.

So, this is what I consider to be a better design, but still flawed as we will see. It uses a P-channel device:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuCEGU.png)</sup>

The inputs to this circuit are INA, which is the analogue signal to be sampled, and IND which is a digital pulse stream to periodically switch on the MOSFET. Those pulses are active-low, because the P-channel MOSFET will be "on" when the gate voltage is significantly *lower* than the source. Note how I have arranged to have this digital signal always far exceed any voltage I expect at the input INA (source), because of the need to guarantee an appropriate \$V_{GS}\$:

[image]

The output is a nice stepped "sample" of the input as INA rises, but as INA falls, the output seems to "follow" the input rather than keeping its value steady. That's because of the parastic drain-source body diode. As INA falls in potential, that diode becomes forward biased, and the capacitor discharges through it. One solution to this problem is to connect two MOSFETs back-to-back, so that there's never a time when both diodes are forward biased:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1IXBm.png)</sup>

[image]

If you are observant, you will have noticed that we broke the rule of "common source", for Q2. Q2 is now a source follower (common drain), but since the gate voltage is so much different from Q2's source, the effect is that the source voltage is clipped to the same potential as the drain, which is actually at the correct potential to be sampled.

There are surely other ways to approach sample-and-hold with a MOSFET (or several MOSFETs), but I think I've illustrated the problems you have with your design.

##### Edit

Actually, just for completeness, I thought I'd show you a design which can work with normal 5V digital pulses:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM33q5.png)</sup>

This is similar to how analogue switch ICs do the job. They use N-channel and P-channel paths to overcome the problem that the switching voltage amplitude is insufficient to bring about the "on" condition of \$V_{GS} > V_{GS(TH)}\$. This arrangement permits the N-channel devices to be switched on for the case where \$V_{INA}\$ is close to ground, and the other P-channel path to be closed when \$V_{INA}\$ is near the positive supply.

The N-channel switching signal must be active-high, but the P-channel devices expect active-low, so IND1 and IND2 are logical inverses of each other. This inversion is performed by unit SUM1 in the schematic.

[image]

Since the footprint of four discrete transistors is greater than a single 8-pin IC, you are probably better off just using an analogue switch IC instead, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

The 741 has too much input bias current, making it a poor choice for sample/hold with small caps or long hold times.

The 741’s input pair actually connects to (-Vee) through several transistors, so leakage in that pair will be toward that supply, which in your case is below ground. This would explain the voltage you’re seeing: the input is leaking towards -Vee.

[image]

Schematic from here: https://www.electronicshub.org/ic-741-op-amp-basics/

Other bipolar-input op-amps will have similar issues to a greater or lesser extent than the 741.

Instead, try a JFET input op-amp, like a TL074 or similar. These have much lower input bias current making them more suitable for sample/hold buffering.

Also, the capacitor itself will leak. Ceramics are leakier than other types like mica or polypropylene. More about that here: https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21801224/whats-all-this-capacitor-leakage-stuff-anyhow

Finally the MOSFET switch has drain-source leakage too, and it also has a body diode. Select the FET it with care, use 2 back-to-back (to negate the body diode) OR use a 4-terminal type (no body diode), and drive it fully ‘off’ when not sampling (more here: More here: [Low Drain-Source MOSFET Leakage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98597/low-drain-source-mosfet-leakage)) Or, consider a JFET instead.

Further reading: https://www.analog.com/media/cn/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-090.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The leakage current of the 741 op-amp's input stage is pulling the capacitor voltage towards the negative rail.

Choose a much better op-amp than the awful 741. It might be in loads of textbooks but its comparatively bad characteristics mean it was superseded by better parts over 40 years ago and by vastly better parts today.

The site is not for part recommendations so I won't recommend one. But select an op-amp with a very high input resistance, and therefore a low input bias (leakage) current. Choose a part with supply rail-to-rail operation, to simplify your life in any future applications of this circuit.